# How to increase or decrease x- and y- axis step for ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to change the increment of the x- and y- axis from one to 1.5.
I tried `PlotRange`...It is not working, I can't define the step of 0.15...

For exemple I would like the following scale -3,-1.5,0,1.5,3 as x- and y- axis instead of -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
How to set these conditions in `ListDensityPlot` ?

Here an exemple of code...

```
   SetOptions[ListDensityPlot,
        Mesh -> None,
        PlotRange -> All,
        ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
        Frame -> True,
        BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 20],
        ImageSize -> UpTo[550]

      ];

data = Table[{#, #2, Sin[#] Cos[#2]} & @@ RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2], {1000}];

graph = ListDensityPlot[data,
  PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[file],
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Linear"},
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &),
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,  LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Black, 20] &)]]
```

Comment: try `FrameTicks->{{Range[-3,3,3/2],Automatic},{Range[-3,3,3/2],Automatic}}`?

Comment: Yes it is workings. Thanks a lot

Comment: How to put the same ticks on the bottom and Right frame ? the step seems to be not the same

Comment: `FrameTicks -> {{N@ticks, N@ticks}, {N@ticks, N@ticks}}`?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but I don't want the number for the top and right frame, just the thicks.

Comment: try `FrameTicks -> {{N@ticks, ticks}, {N@ticks, 
   ticks}}` and `FrameStyle -> {{Automatic,  FontColor -> White}, {Automatic, FontColor -> White}}`

Comment: Good Idea, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ticks = Join[{#, #, {.01, 0}, Thick} & /@ Subdivide[-3, 3, 4], 
   Thread[{Complement[Subdivide[-3, 3, 12], Subdivide[-3, 3, 4] ], ""}]] ;
ListDensityPlot[data,
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap" , 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 20], 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    FrameTicks -> {{N@ticks, Automatic}, {N@ticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]